Error 'UUID' object has no attribute 'replace' on select
There is a table in SQL Server database and I try to select from it using SQLAlchemy and Python.
The table is defined as:
class Orders(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Orders'
    id = Column(mssql.UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, unique=True, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    ...

The select is simple:
orders = session.query(Orders).all()

And when I use mssql+pyodbc and driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0 this select works.
But when I change to mssql+pytds select gives the error:
 File "C:\Users\...\lib\uuid.py", line 174, in __init__
    hex = hex.replace('urn:', '').replace('uuid:', '')
AttributeError: 'UUID' object has no attribute 'replace'

I came into uuid lib and found that hex is expected as string like 'urn:uuid:88888888-8888-8888-8888-888888888888' but in my case it comes as UUID and without urn:uuid: prefix. So the error is understandable but I don't know how to fix it.
I found similar problems with Postgres discussed on StackOverflow: attributeerror-uuid-object-has-no-attribute-replace-when-using-backend-agno and cant-set-uuid-primary-field-in-postgresql-table-flask-sqlalchemy
As recommended there I tried specify (as_uuid=True) and (as_uuid=False) as well, tried to set default=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()) but it didn't help.
How my code should be fixed to avoid this error?
Python is 3.10, SQLAlchemy is 2.0.12, python_tds is 1.15.0, sqlalchemy_pytds is 1.0.0.

SQL Server Native Client 11 hasn't been updated since SQL Server 2012 days and Microsoft no longer distributes it. pytds hasn't had a feature update or release from its original home in over ten years... but someone has taken over the project and migrated it to Github recently so maybe something interesting will be happening there soon. Is there some reason you don't want to use the modern and supported ODBC Driver 18 (or 17) for SQL Server for Linux, macOS or Windows from Microsoft?

Thnx, I didn't know that pytds is outdated. I found that pymssql is what I need. It is being developed nowadays. I don't want SQL Server ODBC driver because it's easeier for me to install python lib on Linux rather than driver.
